# Creating Slack "Special Emails" in Bulk

Tags: python, email, slack, slack-api

- If you go to this URL: https://slackertestwo-oya7554.slack.com/apps/A0F81496D-email?tab=more_info you can use the slack email integration to create a "special email address" that you can use to subscribe to important notifications from any service provided you're on a paid plan.
- You can generate these emails not only for channels but for specific users as well.
- Unfortunately the only way I know how to create this special email is by clicking on the page and selecting a user or channels and then generating the email.

Is there any way I can use the Slack API to generate these emails in bulk? I tried finding documentation on the email integration to see if I could create an app and use python to do this. Can you even call another app in an app you create? Any thoughts or resources will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're on a paid plan, shouldn't your rather ask this question to their customer service? Anyway, it's off topic here, not directly a programming question.

Comment: @mozway I did ask and it's not a native feature. I'm trying to figure out how to do it programmatically. I have some python code that grabs the emails and ids of users in a workspace; don't know how to go about calling this integration to start generating those "special" emails.